# list-style not removing bullet points

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists, sidebarliststyle

I have an ul with 5 li and links i am trying to create a nav bar with. I am very new to HTML and CSS but have done this on a previous mock project with no issues. But for some reason now that I have switched to atom I cant get this to work and do not understand why. If it helps when I type either list-style or list-style-type the color of the code doesn't change as if I was to code color: red; in the same section where red would change colors. The list-style: none; stays gray. Anyone see what I may have done wrong? Is there a step that I have missed?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fitness Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Become an Instructor</a></li>
</ul>
```

style.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {

}

ul li {
list-style: none;
}

ul li a {}
```

Comment: list-style-type:none

Comment: Seems the browser is parsing the CSS correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/znfe9dc1/1/

Comment: Thanks @Kameron for the help, I actually found the problem which I answered on my post if you're curious. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that when trying to split the style.css tab to the right, I deleted the original which wouldn't allow the style.css sheet I was coding on to make any changes. I copied all of the code, moved to a new project, and boom. Good to go.